# How to programmatically read ThunderBolt firmware from UEFI

Tags: security, spi, firmware, pci, uefi

ThunderBolt firmware is stored in its own SPI flash and is updatable from the OS. The system's UEFI firmware is also able to access its configuration data in the flash - users are able to change the ThunderBolt Security Level (SL) from the firmware setup menu during pre-boot. This means there is definitely some way to access the ThunderBolt firmware via some UEFI protocol, but nothing I've tried seems to work.

### What I've Tried

I'm able to successfully identify the ThunderBolt device based on its vendor ID and device ID using the `EFI_PCI_IO_PROTOCOL`.

I initially thought the firmware is an option ROM, so it should be accessible via `EFI_PCI_IO_PROTOCOL.RomImage`. However the value is 0. I then thought the Expansion ROM Base Address Register (XROMBAR) that's inside the PCI Configuration Space may have it. But the XROMBAR is also 0. Extracting the firmware by reading the SPI flash using a hardware programmer, I found that it doesn't have the option ROM's signatures of 0xAA55 and "PCIR" anywhere. So it seems like the firmware is not an option ROM.

I then thought it could be stored in a firmware volume and thus should be accessible via the `EFI_FIRMWARE_VOLUME2_PROTOCOL`. I searched through all the firmware volumes and found a few option ROM, but none of them belong to ThunderBolt (as seen from their vendor ID and device ID).

### Background

I was looking at the [ThunderSpy](https://thunderspy.io/) exploit and the report states that the ThunderBolt firmware is not verified during boot. I thought this was unusual since my thinking then was that the firmware should be an option ROM, and option ROMs must be signed and verified by Secure Boot during every boot. From my findings so far, it seems like the firmware isn't an option ROM and is most likely executed directly on the ThunderBolt controller chip and not on the CPU, hence it is outside the purview of Secure Boot. I'm trying to programmatically access the firmware so as to see if there are ways to defend against ThunderSpy-like attacks where malicious modifications were made to the firmware.

Comment: `SPI` tag is wrong here. Thunderbolt uses its own connection to the chip. You need to  clarify what exactly you mean under Thunderbolt firmware (there are few).

Comment: @0andriy Can you elaborate on what different types of Thunderbolt firmware are there? I'm taking reference from Thunderspy where the researcher extracted the Thunderbolt controller firmware from a Macronix MX25R8035F flash chip. That is the firmware I'm interested in. See [this slide](https://i.blackhat.com/USA-20/Thursday/us-20-Ruytenberg-When-Lightning-Strikes-Thrice-Breaking-Thunderbolt-3-Security.pdf#page=27)